# Can't reset user account password in AD due to Policy's restriction

Tags: active-directory, security

I am deep *** right now and I need your precious help!

Yesterday, I change a user account password in AD (Srv2003). The password was 4 letters, no caps, no numbers. It was set to never expires and no one can change it.

I changed it for a 8 caracters, caps and digits...

So now, we need to have the 4 letters password back. But even if we delete the policy, even if I unlink it, unforce it and force the gpupdate, I can't set the short password on this account!!!!

I've been looking for many and many solutions but nothing can help me this morning.

This: http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=354 cannot fix my problem... still can't change the password.

Please everyone, I need your help!

D.

Comment: Check to see if you can create a new account with a four character password.  This will tell you if the issue is with password length or password age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by the Minimum Password Age has not passed yet

See here for further info:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779758(WS.10).aspx

http://netsecurity.about.com/od/stepbystep/ss/winpasswords_4.htm

Comment: The password policy has been deleted and perform GPUPDATE /FORCE. Even when I repliacted the servers and updated the policy, I'm still unable to change the password for a 4 letters one...

And the second link is about Vista. I don't have any vista WS on my network.

Thanks a bunch!
D.

Comment: The seond one mentions its about Vista, but that setting holds true for Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/2008

Comment: Ok! It's now fixed. After several gpudate and some reboots and maybe, 30 minutes later, the password may now be changed. 

I re-enabled the password policy and now it's fine!

Thanks!